# The coordinates of vertices of regular polygon?

Tags: geometry

For a regular polygon: given the circumscribed circle radius $r$, and the count of edges $n$, and the coordinate of one of the vertices $(x_0, y_0)$, is there a relation to calculate the coordinates of the other $n-1$ vertices? (note that the polygon may have not any edge parallel to the coordinate axes)

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: i know no equations related to the polygon vertices, so i am asking if there is an equation related to this so i start trying from it to derive the coordinates of the other vertices

Comment: Do you know some trigonometry?

Comment: (i will split this comment into 2 parts because of the length),
i know a way as following:
i have the circumscribed circle equation, and from the its diameter and number of polygon edges i can get the polygon side length s, so now i have two equations: (x-x0)+(y-y0)=s^2, and the equation of circle, so from them i get the 2 vertices next to (x0,y0), and from the obtained vertices i get those next to them and so on

Comment: but consider regular polygon with 50 edges, and for example i have the coordinates of the 2nd vertex and the 29th vertex, i would have to calculate the coordinates of all vertices to check that these 2 vertices lie on the same -50 edges- regular polygon, so is there a faster way ?

Comment: i mean by the last comment that i will assume one of the two vertices on the polygon, and then calculate the rest vertices and check that the other vertex is one of those calculated, so i wanted to know if there is faster way to check that those 2 vertices lie on the same 50 sides regular polygon instead of having to calculate all the polygon vertices

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198144/how-to-draw-a-n-sided-regular-polygon-in-cartesian-coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are familiar with some basic trigonometry. If you have a circle of center $C=(x_C,y_C)$ and radius $r$, then every point of the circle can be written as $P=(x_C+r\cos\theta, y_C+r\sin\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle formed by line $CP$ with the $x$-axis.

Your first vertex $P_0=(x_0,y_0)$ can be written in that form too, thus it corresponds to some angle $\theta_0$. As the central angle between two consecutive vertices is $2\pi/n$, the other vertices will then correspond to angles $\theta_1=\theta_0+2\pi/n$, $\theta_2=\theta_0+4\pi/n$, $\theta_3=\theta_0+6\pi/n$, and so on. Once you know $\theta_0$ it is easy to write down the coordinates of the other vertices.

Finally, to get $\theta_0$ notice that $x_0=x_C+r\cos\theta_0$ and $y_0=y_C+r\sin\theta_0$, so that: 
$$
\tan\theta_0={y_0-y_C\over x_0-x_C}.
$$

EDIT

To check that two points $A$ and $B$ on the circle are the vertices of a $n$-polygon, one can compute
$$
\cos(\theta_A-\theta_B)=\cos\theta_A\cos\theta_B+\sin\theta_A\sin\theta_B
={x_A-x_C\over r}{x_B-x_C\over r}+{y_A-y_C\over r}{y_B-y_C\over r}
$$
and
$$
\sin(\theta_A-\theta_B)=\sin\theta_A\cos\theta_B-\cos\theta_A\sin\theta_B
={y_A-y_C\over r}{x_B-x_C\over r}-{x_A-x_C\over r}{y_B-y_C\over r}.
$$
From these you can get $\theta_A-\theta_B$ and check if it is a multiple of $2\pi/n$.