# How to find the coordinates of a regular polygon on a circle given the number of sides of the polygon, the radius, and the coordinates of one point.

Tags: circles, polygons

I need to write a program that calculates the points of the corners of a regular polygon on a circle. I don't need programming help, just the math. I know that one point will always be at the "3 O'Clock position." I'm also given the radius and number of sides of the polygon. How can I find the other points of the polygon (all sides are the same length) on the bounding circle?

Below is an image of an example.

**Example of a 5 sided polygon:**

[image]

Comment: If the center of the circle is always the origin, then you can multiply your first vertex by a rotation matrix repeatedly to get the other vertices.

Comment: How comfortable are you with complex numbers? There is an answer that avoids them (essentially what user469053 is suggesting) but if you know the complex plane then that story is a bit cleaner IMO.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky I'm not really familiar with complex numbers, nor am I familiar with rotation matrices. I learned about matrices before, but I'm not familiar with how to implement one into a Java program.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix 
https://www.baeldung.com/java-matrix-multiplication

Comment: This is the $n=5$ and $y_0=\theta_0=0$ case of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1982828/the-coordinates-of-vertices-of-regular-polygon. The answer allows the center of the polygon to be at $(x_C,y_C)$, for you of course this is just $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

For radius $r$ and $n$ sides you need the points to have coordinates $$(\cos \frac{2\pi t }{n},\sin \frac{2\pi t }{n})$$ for $t=0,1,2, ..., n-1$.

Comment: Where is r in this formula?